# separate functions for home VS other pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need a function that replaces the price in WooCommerce with "Request a quote". On my site's homepage I just need the text, but on the product page (which is a custom product from my travel theme) I need it to be a button.

How can I have 2 functions, one that only works on Home and the other one that works in the rest of the site?

In functions.php, something like:

**IF IS_HOME:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');
function custom_call_for_price() {
return 'Request a quote';
}
```

**AND IF IS_NOT_HOME:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');
function custom_call_for_price() {
$html .= '<a href="#"><input value="Request a quote" type="submit"></a>';
return $html;
}
```

Can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function your_function() 
{
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $output = ...
    }
    else{
        $output = ...
    }
    return $output;
}
```

p.s. It's not needed to use `is_home()`. Whoever needs the technical details, see [`is_front_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_front_page/) and [`is_home`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_home/)

Comment: can you please help me integrate the rest of my code in your function, please? i don't see how I can 'cascade' functions...

Comment: Thanks, I managed it:

    add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');
    function custom_call_for_price() {
    if(is_front_page()){ 
    return 'Request a quote"';
    }else{ 
    $html .= '<a href="#"><input value="Request a quote"" type="submit"></a>';
return $html;
    }
    }

Comment: I changed is_home to is_front_page because it didn't work. it works with is_front_page and I'm going to leave it like this since it works. I need it for this project only, but will keep in mind what you said for future projects. Thanks again!

Comment: @T.Todua not true, what you are saying in the comments: `is_home()` is true on the blog page, no matter, if it is the home page of the site or not. the page for your posts will return true on `is_home()`. `is_front_page()` will return true, if you change the home page to a certain page in settings>reading and load that page (root)..

Comment: @honk31 thanks for further clarification, i made a mistake, your definition is more correct. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
function sv_change_product_price_display( $price ) {

    if(is_home() || is_front_page()){

            $price ='<button>Request Quote</button>';
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_price_display' );
```